# Deploying OpenGL Applications on Windows Mobile

Tags: opengl, windows-mobile

What is involved with deploying OpenGL applications on a Windows Mobile device?  Obviously we can't assume that all the devices have existing OpenGL drivers.  Are there any best practices?  Would it be reasonable to expect to be able to use this for something other than hobby type applications?

Answer (score 2):

Not really an answer. Just sharing some of the links I found in the web:
+ [Samsung OMNIA OpenGL ES/DirectX support, a thread in MSDN forum](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/windowsmobiledev/thread/4529e219-a5a2-4fa3-9eb7-991c6c4ddac5)
+ [OpenGL compatibility layer for Samsung Omnia II, a project in SourceForge](http://sourceforge.net/projects/omnia2gl/)
+ [Some very relevant insights from Joel Ivory Johnson on the topic](http://tinyurl.com/m86a2b)

My short conclusion is, support for OpenGL ES/DirectX depends on the OEM / hardware manufacturer. there is no general answer for all Windows Mobile devices.

You can either ship your application with a software renderer of your choice as a fallback if it fails to detect the existence of manufacturer's optimized implementation; or simply create separate package/installer that targets that specific device. I think you will still be able to have the same code base this way.